# когда в css пишу h4, то изменяются все заголовки а нужно что бы один

Tags: html, css

Пишу сайт,имеется большое количество заголовков и текста как отдельно редактировать заголовки (когда в css пишу h4, то изменяются все заголовки а нужно что бы один)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте нужному заголовку селектор, например класс, и применяйте стили к нему.

```css
.example{font-size:24px;color:red;}
```

```html
<h4>Заголовок 1</h4>
<h4 class="example">Заголовок 2</h4>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @LEV, Если ответ помог, отметьте его верным, что бы другие пользователи видели, что вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу выше: Или обратитесь через уникального родителя , если такие имеются.

Comment: Спасибо большое